# MauiContext Is Null

Tags: c#, firebase-authentication, maui

For the past few weeks, I have been trying to get Firebase working with my Maui app. I have been trying the sample app from [Firebase-Authentication-Dotnet](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet) NuGet package. Looking through the Pull Request I found some code on someone's entry for a Maui app. The code for their Pull Request is found here: [Firebase-Authentication-Dotnet-Maui](https://github.com/JosephGF/firebase-authentication-dotnet). When I run this code through the emulator I have gotten a lot further than I have before getting Firebase to work with Maui.

The login screen now shows all the providers.

[image]

This is new for me as I have been unable to get to this point by myself.

However, when I try to use "Sign In With Google". I get the following error.
[image]

```
File Name: FirebaseAuthClient.cs
```

```
public async Task<UserCredential> SignInWithRedirectAsync(FirebaseProviderType authType, SignInRedirectDelegate redirectDelegate)
{
    var provider = this.config.GetAuthProvider(authType);
    
    if (!(provider is OAuthProvider oauthProvider))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("You cannot sign in with this provider using this method.");
    }

    await this.CheckAuthDomain();

    var continuation = await oauthProvider.SignInAsync();
    // This is the offending code. 
    // I don't know why this line of code raises the "MauiContext Is Null."
    var redirectUri = await redirectDelegate(continuation.Uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
    // continuation.Uri has a value. 

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUri))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var userCredential = await continuation.ContinueSignInAsync(redirectUri).ConfigureAwait(false);

    this.SaveToken(userCredential.User);

    return userCredential;
}
```

MauiContext is null. Even though if I were to paste that `continuation.Uri` into my desktop browser works just fine!

I cannot figure out where this "MauiContex" is. I am struggling to figure this out and I am stuck.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "MauiContext is null."
```

Has anyone else been successful with getting this NuGet to work with their Maui app? If so, will you be willing to share some other providers besides Email?

```
Providers = new FirebaseAuthProvider[]
{
    new GoogleProvider(),
    new FacebookProvider(),
    new AppleProvider(),
    new TwitterProvider(),
    new GithubProvider(),
    new MicrosoftProvider(),
    new EmailProvider() // This is the only provider I have been successful with
},
```

If any you're looking for the code I have cloned this repository: [Firebase-Authentication-Dotnet-Maui](https://github.com/JosephGF/firebase-authentication-dotnet)

Edit: I have reformatted per the recommendations in the comments.

Comment: Relevant code needs to be included as properly formatted text in your post, not linked to an external site.  Code and errors should never be posted as images

Comment: MauiContext is generally a part of handlers, But I am not sure how that is null because of you, I guess maybe try making sure that you are not missing anything in terms of the configuration that's needed for Firebase Auth

Comment: @Jason appreciate the feedback. I have updated it. Let me know if I should update the question further.

Comment: @FreakyAli, That's a possibility that I could be missing something. My guess is it could be possible that something in Android might be missing. Looking at the Android Manifest file Internet and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE are both enabled. Maybe it needs additional permissions? However, if I were to run this in Windows OS everything would work perfectly.

Comment: You should check the Android docs once and see what's the required setup for it to have Firebase Auth, Also windows is irrelevant here